# Check if Html.ValidationSummary() has a value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

How can I check if Html.ValidationSummary() has any errors?

Ultimate result required:

```
<% if(I_HAVE_ERRORS) {%>
<div><%= Html.ValidationSummary() %></div>
<%}%>
```

In other words, how can I determine "I_HAVE_ERRORS"?

Comment: For future reference: to show only non-model errors (when property name is string.Empty): `@if (this.Html.ViewData.ModelState.Any(m => m.Key == string.Empty)) { @this.Html.ValidationSummary(true) }`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
<%if (!Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){%>
```

Answer (score 8):

To use with `razor` syntax

```
@if (!Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // show error
}
```

or you can wrap it up as an extension method

```
public static bool HasErrors(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
    return helper.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid == false;
}
```

Use it as

```
@if (Html.HasError())
{
    // show error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check for errors not related to any specific fields, you could try this:

```
@if(Html.ViewData.ModelState.ContainsKey(string.Empty))
{
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think the most correct way of checking for validation errors (not just auto generated ones based on the model), would be;

```
@if (Model.ViewData.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
{
}
```

This way it will include user generated model errors.